How to use Uniswap's Universal Router without Permit2?
I need to use a geth node hosted account (no local access to the private key) to do some swaps with web3.py, but it seems like it's not possible to generate the Permit2 required signature with eth_sign.  I've only got it to work with account.sign_message and a local private key.
So I'm wondering if I can just do a regular erc20 approval for the router.  I tried it with ganache, but keep getting reverts.  Any suggestions?
